# Hide results from drop-down list when it has no contents

Tags: php, hide

I am a total noob in programming and I am putting a lot of efforts to understand something.

I am preparing my own Cars Dealership page from a script that I got on the web. I almost managed everything except a crucial part.

The webpage is http://car.avedas-rental.com

I imported almost every Manufacturer and associated model of cars, but as a beginner's website I won't have alla the cars.

So I want to use the hide_empty option so that on the search tabs, won't show ALL the list of Manufacturers but only those that have already a car for sale.

I provide you the lines of code that is on the search part:

```
<?php
    // Checking Brand

    if(!empty($_GET['brand_id'])) {
        if($_GET['brand_id'] == 'All Brands') {
            $c_brand = '';
        } else {
            $c_brand = ' AND brand_id='.$_GET['brand_id'];
        }
    } else {
        $c_brand = '';
    }

    // Checking Model
    if (!empty($_GET['model_id'])) {
        if($_GET['model_id'] == 'All Models') {
            $c_model = '';
        } else {
            if($_GET['brand_id'] == 'All Brands') {
                $c_model = '';
            } else {
                $c_model = ' AND model_id='.$_GET['model_id'];
            }
        }
    } else {
        $c_model = '';
    }
```

So I understand that I have to code that i.e. IF No FORD or BMW cars are available for sale, then do not show on the Brands List BMW and Ford as option.

Comment: can you show the full query you are making or give your table structure a bit? If they are in two different tables, you can use a RIGHT JOIN which will only return the manufacturer which has a model for sale.

Comment: I have 2 tables:

tbl_brand
tbl_model

The connection between them is that tbl_model get's connected with tbl_brand with brand_id int.

Comment: I would try the RIGHT JOIN then. I maybe can help w/ the query if you'd show the rest.